# Cannot connect via System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oledb

I ran across a very strange problem and I could not find any related solution so far across the web.

A client has a new server with Windows 2008 R2 (64bit) in which we asked for a SQL Server 2008 R2 installation.

We installed our software on the server which connects to SQL2008 via System.Data.SqlClient without problems.
The software, however, cannot connect to SQL2008 when installed on remote machines. We get a timeout exception.
Notice that we developed a test project with a connection via OLEDB and it seems to work on remote machines. Meaning, we can connect to the database from a remote machine when using an OLEDB connection and we cannot connect to the database when using System.Data.SqlClient.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your connectionstring? off course after masking the vital info.

Comment: The title is misleading. The right title should be "Cannot connect via System.Data.SqlClient". If an administrator sees this, please edit the title. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the full exact message/stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had a same issue within our company network (OLEDb Working - SQLClient didn't). I solved it through adding port 1433(TCP) to the firewall rules.

If it's the error 40 - NamedPipes Issue check within the SQL Configuration Manager(Native Configuration -> Client Protocols) whether named pipes are enabled.

Also check out [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/09/sql-server-fix-error-1326-cannot-connect-to-database-server-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/) - don't forget to read the comments (Those MSSQL2005 Connections issues also often apply to SQL2008 instances...)

Greetings

Therak

Comment: Therak's hint to open ports for SQL server did the magic thing. I searched the web and found a script that opens all ports for SQL server and problem was solved. Thank you for your replies guys. FYI, the script is the following:

Comment: Well, it seems I cannot post the whole script. If anybody wants it, let me know.